# How to check in Python if Windows process is running when its service has stopped?

Tags: python, windows, service, process, long-running-processes

Some Windows processes keep running for a few minutes after their service has stopped. Is there a way in Python to detect that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import os

def getTasks(name):
r = os.popen('tasklist /v').read().strip().split('\n')
print ('# of tasks is %s' % (len(r)))
for i in range(len(r)):
    s = r[i]
    if name in r[i]:
        print ('%s in r[i]' %(name))
        return r[i]
return []

if __name__ == '__main__':
'''
This code checks tasklist, and will print the status of a code
'''

     imgName = 'dwm.exe'

     notResponding = 'Not Responding'

     r = getTasks(imgName)

if not r:
    print('%s - No such process' % (imgName)) 

elif 'Not Responding' in r:
    print('%s is Not responding' % (imgName))

else:
    print('%s is Running or Unknown' % (imgName))
```

[Source](http://www.bogotobogo.com/python/python-Windows-Check-if-a-Process-is-Running-Hanging-Schtasks-Run-Stop.php)

**Important note!!!** As the author of the tutorial stated the platform he used was Windows Server 2012 but this code most likely work with other Windows products. At the very least it should give you and idea on how to do what you want.

Hope its helps!

Answer (score 1):

You can try the `psutil` package and in particular `psutil.process_iter()` (returns an iterator over running processes). This package is used in other profiler packages. Documentation on Process functions can be found [here](http://pythonhosted.org/psutil/#processes).

I don't know how you would find process ids for the service(s) in question if they are not apparent in parent/child pid relationships. I've not tested this on Windows.